# Handle user-to-user requests from iOS at the server

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our iOS app sends User-to-user requests to invite friends using the FB Request Dialog. The invited fb users get a notification showing the request. When they click the request they land at the following URL:

```
www.our_url.com/?request_id=XXXX&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&code=A_LONG_STRING/
```

I was unable to find the official documentation on how to handle this URL and the definitions of the GET parameters.

`request_id` is clear but what exactly is the `code` parameter?

Is it possible to set another URL for this callback? I tried setting `redirect_uri` in the parameters to `[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self]` but that didn't change anything.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

- The code parameter is nothing but the oauth code parameter as discussed here: 
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step6
- The callback URL corresponds to the URL given in the app settings under the section Website with Facebook Login

Hope this helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation that details how to send requests using iOS and also how to handle incoming requests from the Facebook for iOS app:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Basically, if you've configured things correctly, your app will be called by the FB for iOS app with a target_url parameter that includes all the necessary parameters for you to handle the request according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the page you recommend shows how to handle mobile users coming in through the mobile FB app. I'm not worried about mobile users. It already works fine for them. I'm trying to figure out how to best handle users coming in from the desktop browsers.